# Quick binomial test for high number of trials

Tags: probability, approximation, online-resources

I just wanted to perform a quick binomial test for an experiment (Bernoulli trial) with 185 successes out of 459 trials and a (hypothesized) success probability of 0.2. I do not have any mathematical software installed right now and would like to get the result without much effort, i.e., without installing a huge software suite just to perform this one calculation.

I tried a lot of online calculators as well as Excel (which happens to be installed on the PC I am currently working on), but the results I get are either invalid (larger than 1, smaller than zero) or "NaN". I suspect that this is due to floating point errors and/or the limited precision of the underlying floating point calculations. After all, the intermediate values for the CDF calculation will be quite large for my values described above.

WolframAlpha outputs 1 for the following expression

> CDF[BinomialDistribution[459, 0.2], 185]

and 0 for the complement:

> 1-CDF[BinomialDistribution[459, 0.2], 185]

(http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1-CDF%5BBinomialDistribution%5B459%2C+0.2%5D%2C+185%5D)

Similarly, Excel 2010 outputs 1 for the following formula

> =BINOMDIST(185;459;0.2;TRUE)

and a very small negative value (around -2.6E-14) for the complement:

> =1-BINOMDIST(185;459;0.2;TRUE)

Is there any way to get a better approximation for this? I think that the values I am looking for are very close to 1 and 0, respectively, but I would like to know whether they are close enough for practical purposes, i.e., whether they are significant (say, at a significance level of 1 or 5%).

Best regards
Andreas

Comment: One possibility is to use a null of a normal distribution with mean $0.2 \times 459$ and variance $0.2\times 0.8\times 459$.

Comment: @user103828: You mean something like this (Wolfram Alpha syntax)? `1-CDF[NormalDistribution[0.2*459, 0.2*0.8*459], 185]`. This gives me a value of about 0.1. Can I get an estimate of how accurate this approximation by a normal distribution is?

Comment: Yes, that looks about right. but you might have to take the square-root of 0.2*0.8*459... I've written an answer below... I think the probability is very small. Think about how far 185 is from what you expect of about 92 successes (with standard deviation of about 9).

Comment: That's exactly the result I was hoping for. It seemed quite unlikely to me as well, but I wanted to have a calculation to back my "guess".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample size is big enough that we can approximate the binomial distribution with a normal distribution that under the null hypothesis has mean $0.2 \times 459=91.8$ and variance $0.2\times 0.8\times 459=73.44$. Then 
$$
Pr(X \geq 185)=Pr(Z\geq (185-91.8)/8.57) =Pr(Z\geq 10.88) 
$$
The probability that the success probability is $0.2$ is very small.

Comment: To copy from my comment above: Can I get an estimate of how accurate this approximation by a normal distribution is?

Comment: In general I think the normal distribution approximates the binomial quite well... regardless the eyeball test is that 0.2 probability of success is very unlikely http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Normal_approximation

Comment: The normal distribution approximation is typically not so good in the "tails" of the distribution, which is definitely what we are looking at here.

Comment: @user2566092: Is there any way to get an estimate of how far off I will be (without calculating the exact values for the binomial distribution, of course)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add very small positive numbers, compute the log of each number instead of the number (easy for binomial distribution, the multiplication/division turns into a sum) and then sort the logged values from smallest to largest. Suppose you have computed $A$, the log of the sum of the first $k$ numbers, and let $B$ be the log of the $k+1$th number. Assume without loss of generality that $A \leq B$ (otherwise just swap them). Then

$$\log(e^A + e^B) = A + \log(1 + e^{B-A})$$

and if $A$ and $B$ are close enough then this will give you a non-trivial result and avoid underflow and overflow. If you're doing a one-sided statistical test, then just add up the (log) probabilities of getting that many successes or higher, all the way up to the maximum possible number of successes.

Comment: I see your point, but this would only help me if I calculated the results "manually". I am looking for a more practical solution, even though I like the idea with the log to add numbers with different orders of magnitude.

Comment: I guess it depends on what you mean by "manually." I could write a computer program in about 10-15 minutes that would give you the p-value to high accuracy on the log scale. But if you don't know how to program then I guess you either have to go totally "manual" or rely on some existing software like Excel.

Comment: I could also write a computer program or look up the formulas and type them into Excel, but I am looking for a quicker, i.e., less time-consuming, way.